# Why I can't award bounty points?

Tags: support, bounty

I got a great answer for this question
[Number of China orbital launches by year](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49179/number-of-china-orbital-launches-by-year)

Then I put a bounty and chose "Reward existing answer"

But I cant give the points to that user, why is that?

Later edit:

I started a few more bounties, I get the same thing, the bounty points button is in gray and I can not use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you wait 24 hours after starting the bounty before trying to award it? There's a waiting period before you can give it out.

From the [FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/228367):

> **How do I award a bounty?**
> A bounty can be awarded 24 hours after the bounty was started.

Comment: I missed that part, I could award the bounty now, thanks